# How to get all event_member by paging?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit, paging, facebook-fql

I want get all members of event, but i dont result all members. I have problem with paging.

For example:

This public event has about 12 000 invited users:

```
http://www.facebook.com/events/318789194806929/
```

Link for get users after 5000 and this result is empty:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=318789194806929%2Finvited%3Foffset%3D5000%26limit%3D20%26format%3Djson
```

or fql(all users)

```
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=318789194806929 LIMIT 100000
```

How I get all (invited) users of this event?

Thank you for all hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been seeing in the API where there's a 5000 maximum limit on much of everything via the graph API.  Sometimes it's even lower than that.  Maybe that's the extent as to what Facebook feels is scalable in a public facing API.  They might have partner APIs that are far less restrictive.   since your event is pulling an amazing 12,000 users, you might be able to bend Facebook's ear with some advertising revenue and become a partner with them.  ;)